# Website background Full-Screen in digital signage system

Tags: css, sinatra

I'm using a Raspberry Pi and Screenly-OSE as a Digital Signage solution for our pharmacy. I display various ads along with the overnights. I'm using a very simple Sinatra application to to [serve overnights](http://piseli.net/overnights/drama). Works great except from a small detail which bugs me a lot, there's a white space available there: see [picture](http://d.pr/i/MCrn) .

I'm using the following very simple css file:

```
body {
    /* background-color: #246013; */
    background-image:url('moon.jpg');
    color: white; 
    text-align: center;
    font: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#content{
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}

#footer{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    color: #D6D6D6;
    font: 14px "Courier New", Courier, mono;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: bold;
}


h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h5 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I wonder if there's a way to get full-screen background cover. The background picture cover goes along with the text, some days *overdays* are displayed and if the overdays are 5 or 6 the entire screen is covered.

I know I can simulate this behavior by adding `br/` and/or counting the text lines displayed. But I wonder if there's any other other, more *natural* way of achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure setting both html and body to 100% height to make them cover it all.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```